# How To Get The Current Screen Size When I Click Right Menu In Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I have a Chrome extension, and when a custom context menu is clicked on a webpage, I want to retrieve the screen dimensions within a service worker. How can I achieve this without injecting scripts into the web page?

My specific requirement is to create a pop-up dialog when right-clicking on a menu, and this dialog needs to be centered on the screen. Therefore, I need to obtain the screen's width and height.

I can open dialog in popup like this :

```js
const showSelectPopUp = () => {
  const width = 420;
  const height = 600;
  const left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2);
  const top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
  // open dialog
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: 'src/selector/selector.html',
    type: 'popup',
    width: width,
    height: height,
    left: Math.round(left),
    top: Math.round(top),
  });
}
```

How to do it in service_worker?

Comment: Wouldn't you want it centered in the browser window?

Comment: Do service workers have access to `window`?

Comment: service_worker does not support window objects, 
Maybe I didn't describe it clearly, so I modified the description again.